# While debugging a Java program in IntelliJ, how to show Bytecode that is being executed?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ to debug a Java program. In my current case that happens to be IntelliJ itself -- to debug a problem in it -- but a similar problem occurred in the past with other code.

While single-stepping, at a certain point when stepping into a method, IntelliJ won't show the code that is being executed anymore. I am used to stepping through decompiled byte code when source is not available, but in this case IntelliJ won't show *anything* -- no source code, no byte code, nothing. This happens when stepping from `RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl` into `GradleProjectResolver`.

Quite suspiciously, the problem happens exactly when stepping from a class that comes from an `UrlClassLoader`, into a class from a `PluginClassLoader`.

I'm aware that the debugger will have problems associating the bytecode being executed with source code when the bytecode comes from a class loader of unknown nature, since there is no well-defined mechanism for that. Please note that I am totally fine with stepping through decompiled code. (Even stepping through bytecode instructions would be fine, but AFAIK IntelliJ does not support that). I'm not sure how to provide matching source code myself, so I'd rather see the bytecode to be sure I'm not seeing false information.

What I do not understand is why IntelliJ won't show me that bytecode. Unlike source code, the bytecode *is* avaiable since after all, it is being executed right now.

What should I do to make IntelliJ show the bytecode being executed?

**Update: Steps to reproduce**

- Use IntelliJ to create an IntelliJ plugin project
- create a new folder with an empty build.gradle file in it
- Run a "guest" instance of IntelliJ in debug mode
- Import the empty gradle project
- In the "host" IntelliJ, go to RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo and set a breakpoint to the inner call to this.myDelegate.resolveProjectInfo
- In the "guest" IntelliJ, hit the Gradle re-import button. It should hit the breakpoint.
- Step into the function being called. This will show the frame on the stack, but no code -- not even raw or decompiled bytecode.

Comment: Don't you have those classes excluded from stepping in "Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Stepping"?

Comment: Unfortunately, not.

Comment: Is it possible to provide sample project demonstrating the issue?

Comment: On the IntelliJ side (the code being debugged), I set up a plain plugin project with IntelliJ itself and run debug without changing any code. (This was the easiest way I knew to debug a mostly unchanged IntelliJ). The Gradle project I imported is more complex, and if needed I'll try to explain (it's all on GitHub, so nothing to hide). But since the problem is with the "host" debugger, I'd hope that the same happens for importing *any* Gradle project.

Comment: I added steps to reproduce to the question.

Comment: Seems like a bug or a limitation of the debugger implementation, you may try to create a Bug report/Support request in the IDEA's issue tracker for asking: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Answer (score -3):

You are possibly debugging a library that had been compiled without debug infos. For this purpose, the Java compiler has the command-line option "-g".

I assume you do not understand what bytecode is. This is a bunch of numeric values which cannot be displayed in a similar manner as source code. You would not be able to read bytecode.

What you are usually seeing is decompiled byte code, which depends on the existence of debug infos.

Comment: I am totally able to read bytecode when it's at least disassembled with javap -c since I have written a simple JVM myself. Debug info would help, but I'm fine without. Decompiled byte code does NOT depend on debug info in the IntelliJ debugger, it's just a bit less readable then (e.g. no local variable names, just var1, var 2, etc.) Finally, what I am seeing is actually NOTHING, not even the raw byte values. IntelliJ won't even open an editor pane for the class being executed when I step into it.

Comment: Ok, then sorry for the bad answer.